# How to authorized only method in backend

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using spring security. How I can authorized only methods in my application ? So I created spring context where all pages are permitted. And in method which I want to authrorized I add annotation @PreAuthorize. Problem is that this method can be called even user is not authorized. Why ?

spring.security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />

        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout/success" logout-url="/logout"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        <custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

method which I want to authorized:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public ExtDirectStoreReadResult<Person> loadPeople(ExtDirectStoreReadRequest request) throws Exception {
...
    }
```

login method:

```
    public ExtDirectFormPostResult login(Person person, BindingResult result) {
...

    }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" metadata-complete="true">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext.xml
            classpath:spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/controller/api.js</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/controller/api-debug.js</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config/>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list-->

</web-app>
```

Comment: what is your concrete problem and how did you try to solve it?

Comment: you didnt see my code which I post ? My problem that I want to protect only method in my backend not web pages

Comment: i actually saw a huge heap of code... and i do not understand your last sentence. sorry

Comment: never mind question already answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable that feature using following element in your spring.security.xml file

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Comment: You welcome with further info [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html)